# No me actualiza la base de datos usando php artisan migrate

Tags: laravel

Resulta que estoy intentando agregar nuevas tablas usando el sistema de migracion de Laravel. Estoy ejecutando desde CMD php artisan migrate y luego pongo php artisan migrate:status para ver los estados de cada migracion, el cual no me sube a la DB (ya comprobado) solo me sube los que estan por defectos de laravel

Comment: Hay algún problema si ejecutas todas las migraciones de nuevo?

Comment: Si ejecuto todo de nuevo la consola me dice que hay tablas repetidas (las que estan por defecto) pero de nuevo pongo el status y me sale N, es decir, no se han subido.

Comment: Has probado utilizar `php artisan migrate:fresh`. Pruébalo y luego vuelve a realizar todas las migraciones

Comment: Con php artisan migrate:fresh se ejecutarán de nuevo todas las migraciones sin importar que tablas estén ya

Comment: Borra las tablas manualmente, y después migralas con el comando `php artisan migrate` sino utiliza `php artisan migrate:refresh`

Comment: Elimine todas las tablas por defecto de laravel, al ejecutar php artisan migrate me vuelve a crear las tablas por defecto mas no las que yo cree y me sale un error en cmd, unas excepciones ejecutadas de laravel: Syntax error or access violation, de Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException